# Drush: Make site alias read only

Tags: drush

I like having site alias defined for easy Drupal management for backing up, syncing dev site with live etc.

But I am afraid of having great loses if I mistyped the drush command having order of site aliases interchanged.

```
drush sql-sync @dev @live
```

Instead of:

```
drush sql-sync @live @dev
```

Other possibilities include:

```
drush rsync @dev @live
```

Is there any option that I can set while defining site aliases that make a site ready only in drush commands? I tried to find one, including drush source code, but didn't succeed.

Of course, outside of drush I can create separate user account that only have ready only access to the site. Also extra database user with no `CREATE`/`UPDATE` permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to do it with `drush_hook_COMMAND_validate()`.

Example: https://github.com/Lullabot/drupal-boilerplate/blob/master/drush/commands/policy.drush.inc

Comment: That is a good idea!